# Is it possible to design on an 8pt Grid with the Bootstrap 4 Grid?

Tags: grid, bootstrap-4

Was wondering if it is possible to design on an 8pt Grid System in Sketch, Photoshop etc... that will be able to match up to the new Bootstrap 4 Grid?

They don't seem to match up currently was wondering if it was at all possible?

Many thanks